# Why does "p4 integrate" operate on more files than "p4 interchanges" lists?

Tags: perforce-integrate

I maintain a family of branches, `.../base/...`, `.../base-staging/...`, `.../base-production/...`. Changes are usually made in `base`, reviewed, and then integrated out to `base-staging` and eventually `base-production`. Before an integration, I typically do a `p4 interchanges` to confirm that only expected changes will be carried forward.

Usually this works. But sometimes `p4 integrate` pulls over files and changes not listed by `p4 interchanges`. By my understanding, that shouldn't happen! What am I misunderstanding?

Details:

1. Ancient history:

   1. create `.../base/...`
   2. `p4 integrate base/... base-staging/...`
   3. `p4 integrate base/... base-production/...`
2. make changes in `.../base/...` and `submit`
3. `p4 interchanges base/... base-staging/...`

   1. review and approve
4. `p4 integrate base/... base-staging/...`

   1. whoah! what are all these other listed files???
   2. review: real changes, made well before my `interchanges` command, but not mentioned therein

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume we're talking about a relatively recent server release -- on older releases "interchanges" will indeed match exactly what "integrate" lists, but in newer releases they diverge a bit in order to address the subtly different common use cases of the two commands.

One of the functions of "integrate" is to record history that ensures that future integrates behave in a predictable fashion.  In some edge cases that means opening a file for integrate even though no actual changes need to be propagated to the target, so that it can be recorded that the file is up to date.  A very simple example: make a change in A, ignore from A to B, merge from B to C, now merge A to C.  Your expectation will typically be that integration is "transitive" such that if A->B reports nothing to do and B->C reports nothing to do then A->C will report nothing to do; if the B->C merge skips the change because it was an "ignore", though, then the A->C merge has no record that the B->C merge was ever even attempted, and it will propagate the change, violating the expectation of transitivity.

"Interchanges", however, does not record any history, and it is usually desirable for it to limit its scope to report only source changes that are not present in the target.  It's therefore tuned to produce a smaller set of changes than you might get by running "integrate".  The changes that are excluded from "interchanges" but included by "integrate" are typically going to be ones that do not strictly require merging, but that will probably make it easier to merge the "required" changes if they're included as well.

Using the "-Rs" flag on "integrate" will cause it to mimic the "interchanges" behavior and select the absolute minimum set of source revisions.  It's briefly described in this old blog post from when it was introduced:

http://www.perforce.com/blog/101206/p4-integ-3-exciting-things-afoot